# Update only part of the column - multiple rows

Tags: php, postgresql

As part of migrating a website to HTTPS, I'm changing HTTP URLs in blog articles to relative URLs.

**Current data** in the `articles` table:

```
╔════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ content                                                       ║
╠════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ lorem ipsum <a href='http://www.example.com/'>link</a> etc    ║
║  2 ║ see more <a href='http://www.example.com/page.html'>here</a>  ║
║  3 ║ bla bla bla <img src='http://www.example.com/image.jpg' />    ║
╚════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

**Desired output** with relative URLs:

```
╔════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ content                                                       ║
╠════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ lorem ipsum <a href='//www.example.com/'>link</a> etc         ║
║  2 ║ see more <a href='//www.example.com/page.html'>here</a>       ║
║  3 ║ bla bla bla <img src='//www.example.com/image.jpg' />         ║
╚════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Notes:

- There's few hundred rows with these hardcoded links.
- Each row can contain more links.

---

I was thinking about going over each row, changing the links with regex and then updating the row.

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT id,content FROM articles WHERE content LIKE '%http://www.example.com%'");
while ( $row = $query->fetch_row() ) {
  $updatedContent = /* some regex to remove the "http:" part */
  $db->query("UPDATE articles SET content = ...");
}
```

---

But as I'd like to learn a new thing, my question is:

**Is there an other way?** Possibly some **regex in PostgreSQL** that would allow to **update only part of the column** and not waste resources on going over hundreds of rows with thousands of characters in each of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need PHP for this.  It can be done via a simple database query:

`UPDATE articles SET content = REPLACE(content, 'http:', '');`

Comment: you can also filter with WHERE:

`UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field , 'http:', '')
WHERE your_field LIKE '%http%'`